# Purchase additional checked baggage

Tags: luggage, sas

I am looking at a flight in Kayak and Cheapoair. In both places, I see a SAS flight with ticket category GoLight that has 1 checked baggage included. But in the [SAS website](https://www.flysas.com/gb-en/fly-with-us/ticket-options/ticket-types/), I see no checked baggage is included with this ticket type. Which one would be correct information?

Second question, can I pay and take more checked luggages with GoLight ticket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the SAS website (that you linked to), if you click the link 'checked baggage' (https://www.flysas.com/gb-en/travel-info/baggage/checked/), you get to a site where it says: "Checked baggage is not included in SAS Go Light, but it can be added for a fee". You can buy it right there.

I would not trust offers from third parties, but it could be they sell you a bundled ticket price with luggage. It could also be that the fine print reads on page 473 'the details of the allowed luggage are defined by the airline", and you are out of luck.

Comment: You should definitely check the conditions very carefully. It may be that the price on Kayak etc includes checked baggage. It might be that SAS has a deal with some aggregators/agents to include baggage or other extras. But even with a reputable site, mistakes can be made and some travel websites may be less reputable than you think. And definitely if you book you should double-check all the conditions as soon as possible afterwards and try and rectify any problem immediately (probably the worst that will happen is you pay a bit more, so you may think it's worthwhile taking the chance).